# how to assign input value to span Id?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the simple program to create draggable text on Image function. can you suggest me to get user input from input box and shown it to (Drag Now) Text which is draggable here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" >
<form>
   <select onchange="ChangeBackgroundFont(this,'font');" size="1">
      <option value="0.1">0.1</option>
      <option value="0.25">0.25</option>
      <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
      <option value="0.75">0.75</option>
      <option selected="1.0">1.0</option>
      <option value="1.25">1.25</option>
      <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
      <option value="1.75">1.75</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
   <select name="color" type="text" onchange="ChangeBackgroundFont(this,'background');" >
      <option value="select">Select</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
      <option value="white">White</option>
      <option value="black">Black</option>
   </select>
   <div id="draggable-element"> <span id="fontbackgroundTest" style="font-size-adjust: 0.6">Drag Me</span> </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ChangeBackgroundFont (selectTag,type) {      
          if(type=="font") {     
              // Returns the index of the selected option
              var whichSelected = selectTag.selectedIndex;
              // Returns the selected options values
              var selectState = selectTag.options[whichSelected].text;
              var fontTest = document.getElementById ("fontbackgroundTest");
              if ('fontSizeAdjust' in fontTest.style) {
                  fontTest.style.fontSizeAdjust = selectState;
              } else {
                  alert ("Your browser doesn't support this example!");
              }
            }else{
                document.getElementById("fontbackgroundTest").style.color = selectTag.value;
            }
        }
    </script> 
<img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/> 
<script>
var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
  x_pos = 0,
  y_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
  x_elem = 0,
  y_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element

// Will be called when user starts dragging an element
function _drag_init(elem) {
  // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
  selected = elem;
  x_elem = x_pos - selected.offsetLeft;
  y_elem = y_pos - selected.offsetTop;
}

// Will be called when user dragging an element
function _move_elem(e) {
  x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
  y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;
  if (selected !== null) {
    selected.style.left = (x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
    selected.style.top = (y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
  }
}

// Destroy the object when we are done
function _destroy() {
  selected = null;
}

// Bind the functions...
document.getElementById('draggable-element').onmousedown = function() {
  _drag_init(this);
  return false;
};

document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
document.onmouseup = _destroy;
</script>
<style>
 body {
      padding: 10px
    }

    #draggable-element {
      width: 100px;
      height: 10px;
      background-color: #;
      color: black;
      padding: 10px 12px;
      cursor: move;
      position: absolute;
      /* important (all position that's not `static`) */
    }

</style>
</body>
</html>
```

I know its easy but couldnt find the easy way to change input to reflect it in span id. pls help me to do it.

Comment: Did you mean `Drag Me` instead of `Drag Now`? You have `Drag Me` in your code

Comment: No, whatever i type in input box value should replace with (Drag Me) font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your "input" element code as below.

```
<input type="text" id="draggablevalue" onchange="document.getElementById('fontbackgroundTest').innerHTML  = document.getElementById('draggablevalue').value;">
```

I have added an onchange event which gets triggered whenever there is a value change in the input field. 
Within this onchange event, i have fetched the updated value and set it as the value of the draggable span element.

Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/7r2007nn/

Comment: [Here is a jsFiddle of your solution](https://jsfiddle.net/7r2007nn/). You are welcome to include it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onkeyup event on your input box...whenever a key is press it will update your span element

example

```
document.getElementById('input').onkeyup= function() {
document.getElementById('draggable-element').children[0].innerHTML=this.value;
}
```

snippet

```css
 body {
      padding: 10px
    }

    #draggable-element {
      width: 100px;
      height: 10px;
      background-color: #;
      color: black;
      padding: 10px 12px;
      cursor: move;
      position: absolute;
      /* important (all position that's not `static`) */
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id='input' >
   <form>
      <select onchange="ChangeBackgroundFont(this,'font');" size="1">
         <option value="0.1">0.1</option>
         <option value="0.25">0.25</option>
         <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
         <option value="0.75">0.75</option> 
         <option selected="1.0">1.0</option>
         <option value="1.25">1.25</option>
         <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
         <option value="1.75">1.75</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
      <select name="color" type="text" onchange="ChangeBackgroundFont(this,'background');" >
           <option value="select">Select</option>
           <option value="blue">Blue</option>
           <option value="green">Green</option>
           <option value="white">White</option>
           <option value="black">Black</option>
       </select>

<div id="draggable-element">
      <span id="fontbackgroundTest" style="font-size-adjust: 0.6">Drag Me</span>
</div>  
</form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function ChangeBackgroundFont (selectTag,type) {      
          if(type=="font") {     
              // Returns the index of the selected option
              var whichSelected = selectTag.selectedIndex;
              // Returns the selected options values
              var selectState = selectTag.options[whichSelected].text;
              var fontTest = document.getElementById ("fontbackgroundTest");
              if ('fontSizeAdjust' in fontTest.style) {
                  fontTest.style.fontSizeAdjust = selectState;
              } else {
                  alert ("Your browser doesn't support this example!");
              }
            }else{
                document.getElementById("fontbackgroundTest").style.color = selectTag.value;
            }
        }
    </script>
<img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>

<script>
var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
  x_pos = 0,
  y_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
  x_elem = 0,
  y_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element

// Will be called when user starts dragging an element
function _drag_init(elem) {
  // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
  selected = elem;
  x_elem = x_pos - selected.offsetLeft;
  y_elem = y_pos - selected.offsetTop;
}

// Will be called when user dragging an element
function _move_elem(e) {
  x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
  y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;
  if (selected !== null) {
    selected.style.left = (x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
    selected.style.top = (y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
  }
}

// Destroy the object when we are done
function _destroy() {
  selected = null;
}

// Bind the functions...
document.getElementById('draggable-element').onmousedown = function() {
  _drag_init(this);
  return false;
};

document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
document.onmouseup = _destroy;
document.getElementById('input').onkeyup= function() {
document.getElementById('draggable-element').children[0].innerHTML=this.value;

}
</script>
<style>
 body {
      padding: 10px
    }

    #draggable-element {
      width: 100px;
      height: 10px;
      background-color: #;
      color: black;
      padding: 10px 12px;
      cursor: move;
      position: absolute;
      /* important (all position that's not `static`) */
    }

</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added an id to your input tag